# Undefined variable while fetching data from mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to php n I'm trying to make a phone to timezone converter.
I'm getting the error undefined variable '$result' on line 49
How do I resolve it.
Also if you can find out any other mistakes I've made
Please chck for errors I'm making
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        Phone number:

```
    <button type="submit" name="submit" action="submit">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
    <?php
        $servername = "127.0.0.1";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $ccode=$_POST["phone"];
            // Create connection
            $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

            // Check connection
            if ($db->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
            } 
        $pattern = '/^\(?[\d]{1,4}\)?( |-)?/';
        if(preg_match($pattern, $ccode, $matches))
        {

            $code = $matches[0];
        } else $code = substr($ccode, 0, 4);
        $q = "SELECT nicename FROM country.country WHERE phonecode=$code";
        if($query = $db->query($q)) 
        {
            $record = $query->fetch_assoc();
        } else echo "<br/>NO RECORD";
        echo '<pre>';print_r($record);

        if (empty($_POST["phone"]))
        {
            echo "<p>Please write a Phone Number!</p>";
        }
        $abb = "SELECT zone_id FROM zone INNER JOIN country on country.country_code = zone.country_code
                WHERE country.country_name = " . $record['nicename'];
        if($query = $db->query($abb)) 
        {
            $result = $query->fetch_assoc();
        } else echo "<br/>NO RECORD";
        echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
    ?>
</body>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did u run this code in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: yes it works good there

Comment: paste your full error you get!!!!!

Comment: I believe the problem is the print_r($record), and that's because $record is not always set. If the query fails, or does not return any values, then $record does not exist. But later in your script, you do use $record, and that's where it goes wrong.

Comment: Undefined variable: result in D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\Timezone\index.php on line 49

Comment: Also I see the second query. I assume country_name is a string? And so $record['nickname'] is a string? Then you must put quotes around it, like so: country.country_name = '" . $record['nickname'] . "'

Comment: Only one reason I can see here i.e. your query `$abb` isn't executing successfully only then `Undefined variable` can show

Comment: I think $record variable works fine problem is with the sql syntax

Comment: I dont know how else to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this way it will works. I'm not sure about $code, if he contains the right information, you can check that by echo'ing the $code.

```
    if(preg_match($pattern, $ccode, $matches))
    {
        $code = $matches[0];
    } else { $code = substr($ccode, 0, 4); }

    $q = "SELECT nicename FROM country WHERE phonecode=$code";
    if($query = $db->query($q)) 
    {
        $record = $query->fetch_assoc();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($record);
    } else { echo "<br/>NO RECORD"; }


    $abb = "SELECT zone_id FROM zone INNER JOIN country on country.country_code = zone.country_code
            WHERE country.country_name = '" . $record['nicename'] . "'";
    if($query = $db->query($abb)) 
    {
        $result = $query->fetch_assoc();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
        //Here $result will exist!
    } else { echo "<br/>NO RECORD"; }
    // You had your $result here, and here, the result may not exist, 
    // depending if the query succeeded or not.
    // Same counts for the query above.
```

There were 2 problems as far as I can tell.

1 was that you tried to print $record, while $record may not have existed, and the same counts for $result.

2 was the zone-query, if you check if a column/field equals a certain string, then make sure the string has quotes around itself. So country_name='something'. You didn't have these quotes around $record['nicename'], so whatever came out of $record['nicename'], he thought it was a column/field, but not a value to check upon.

Comment: Well thanks that was helpful but its still not giving any result for $result variable so it just shows no record. Upto this point it works fine

Comment: Well that's strange. But at least no more undefined variables, however, having said that, if the first query does not find any results, then $record['nicename'] does not exist as well! Which will also lead to a invalid/bugged query. Does the script show you that $record contains information?

Comment: Do you get to see 'NO RECORD' or nothing at all for the second query? I believe if it shows NO RECORD, then there is still something wrong with the query-syntax. Echo'ing $abb will be helpful to see where the problem lays. If it shows nothing at all, then that means it just didn't find any results.

Comment: It says NO RECORD and on echoing $abb it just prints out the whole sql statement: SELECT zone_id FROM zone INNER JOIN country on country.country_code = zone.country_code WHERE country.country_name = ''

Comment: There's nothing between the quotes? That's weird. That would mean $record['nicename'] doesn't contain any value.